# On Memory Allocation and C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

And I quote from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366533(VS.85).aspx:

> The malloc function has the
>   disadvantage of being run-time
>   dependent. The new operator has the
>   disadvantage of being compiler
>   dependent and language dependent.

Now the questions folks:

a) What do we mean that malloc is run-time dependent? What kind of dynamic memory allocation functions can be independent of run-time? This statement sounds real strange.

b) new is language dependent? Of course it should be right? Are HeapAlloc, LocalAlloc etc language independent?

c) From a pure performance perspective are the MSVC provided routines preferable?

Arpan

Comment: comment on his answer with comments, not here.

Comment: really obscure to me; of course every "real" request of memory done at run-time, is run-time dependent. The new operator is of course lang dependent ... but compiler dependent?! if we're talking about C++, it's standardized and I expect that `new` behaviour is not compiler dependent; how it achieves its purpose is of course compiler dependent (but it is also an uninteresting detail) and also system dependent...(as malloc after all) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) In this case I think they're eliding "run-time library" to "run-time". In other words it depends on the implementation in your C library.

b) Indeed new is C++ specific. HeapAlloc, etc are technically usable in C and C++.

c) They can't be used to create C++ objects because they won't call constructors so the point is pretty moot. In C++ you should use new and delete.

Comment: And redefine global `operator new` if you want to use a portable allocator.

Comment: Not to mention HeapAlloc and friends are also windows specific - the only way you'd be able to make your code portable if you use those is by making your own HeapAlloc for other platforms... why bother when you can just use malloc/free or new/delete?

Answer (score 5):

The problems with malloc and new arise when you use DLLs.  Depending on build options, a DLL may have its own copy of the CRT.  That makes it use its own heap to allocate memory from, a *different* heap than the one used by the EXE.  This causes failure when memory is allocated by one module and released by another.  Very common when you use STL.

One way to solve it is by compiling code with the /MD option.  That forces use of a shared copy of the CRT, stored in its own DLL.  Problem solved, there's now only one allocator, using a single heap.

This issue also arises with COM, it allows different languages to interop.  They would of course never share an allocator since those language have different runtime support libraries.  By contract, COM code must use a single allocator provided by the COM runtime support, CoTaskMemAlloc().

Note that HeapAlloc() cannot solve this problem.  It requires a handle to a heap, returned by HeapCreate().  Different modules would have to share that handle to avoid trouble.

---

Update: addressed in VS2012, the CRT now allocates from a shared heap, the default process heap (GetProcessHeap function).

Answer (score 0):

a) It means that the behaviour of malloc depends on the version of the C-runtime you compile against.

b) HeapAlloc and LocalAlloc are Win32 API functions.  They are indeed both runtime and language independant.

c) That's impossible to answer without knowing how the runtime routines are implemented.  I suspect that their performance is comprable.  In any case, if you go with the new operator, then you always have the option of overriding it later if necessary.  Remember, premature optimization is the root of all evil. ;)

One final note: LocalAlloc and GlobalAlloc are *slow*.  You shouldn't use them unless forced to by a crufty old Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that is a curious statement to appear in documentation without an accompanying explanation. Could it be a hold over from when C++ was introduced?  I can only guess as to the answers to your questions:

a) Perhaps they mean to contrast it with link/load time allocation, such as for globals, constants, and `static` data. Or perhaps they mean to contrast it with stack allocation, such as the `alloca` family.

b) They may be drawing attention to the fact that you shouldn't allocate memory with C++ `new`, then pass ownership of that memory to library routine which may `free()` it. So in that sense, the result of the allocation is language-specific.

c) Use C++ `new` and `delete`. You have to assume that the underlying C++ allocator in the MSVC runtime is as fast as, if not identical to, the C-style system calls. Just remember that `new` and `delete` do more than allocate and free memory. They are not purely substitutable with `malloc` and `free` or with other C-style allocators.